# Kafka Stream binder unit tests with junit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to write Kafka stream binder unit test cases that use a functional approach.

```
@FunctionalSpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class},properties = {"spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092"})

@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
        brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092","port=9092","socket.request.max.bytes=409296129"},
        topics = {"inputTopic"}, controlledShutdown = true)
@DirtiesContext
public class Test {

    @Test
    public void testKstreamBinderWithPojoInputAndStringOuput() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("group-id",
                "false", embeddedKafka);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerProps);
        consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, "inputTopic");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class); //Springboot application class
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run("--server.port=0",
                "--spring.jmx.enabled=false",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.process-in-0=input",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.process-out-0=output",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=inputTopic",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=outputTopic",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms=1000",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde"
                        + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde"
                        + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.applicationId=StreamProcessorStorecloseApplication-xyz",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers="
                        + embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        try {
            receiveAndValidateInputTopic();
            // Assertions on StreamBuilderFactoryBean
            StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = context
                    .getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
            CleanupConfig cleanup = TestUtils.getPropertyValue(streamsBuilderFactoryBean,
                    "cleanupConfig", CleanupConfig.class);
            assertThat(cleanup.cleanupOnStart()).isFalse();
            assertThat(cleanup.cleanupOnStop()).isFalse();
        }
        finally {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
 private void receiveAndValidateInputTopic() {
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                senderProps);
        KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf, true);
        template.setDefaultTopic("inputTopic");
        template.sendDefault("{\"id\":\"123\"}");
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer,
                "inputTopic");
        assertThat(cr.value().contains("Count for product with ID 123: 1")).isTrue();
    }
```

In receiveAndValidateInputTopic() method I am sending POJO object which is expected by inputTopic and checking for expected output as by doing isTrue(), Test case is failing. How this `getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);`

Kstream Bean -- This is the one I got reference on github. I am working on similar requirement.

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public static class ProductCountApplication {

        @Bean
        public Function<KStream<Object, Product>, KStream<Integer, String>> process() {
            return input -> input.filter((key, product) -> product.getId() == 123)
                    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))
                    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(new JsonSerde<>(Product.class),
                            new JsonSerde<>(Product.class)))
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(5000)))
                    .count(Materialized.as("id-count-store")).toStream()
                    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key().id,
                            "Count for product with ID 123: " + value));
        }

    }

    static class Product {

        Integer id;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site. Please [edit] your question to include your own attempt at solving your problem and any errors you are running into. Refer [help] on asking good questions

Comment: @OneCricketeer is this much information good enough? And thank you for letting me know that this is not a tutorial site. If possible please give some suggestions and references if something is available.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will say that `TopologyTestDriver` class from Kafka should be used instead to test Kafka Streams... You should not start a web server to test your kafka specific code... Nor do you explicitly need any Spring-kafka classes beyond the embedded broker. KafkaTemplate and consumer are for basic producer/consumer API, not Kafka Streams or Spring Cloud Steams binder... If you want to test these, Spring source code would be best place to look / copy

Comment: If possible can you please provide any link or something? I am new to spring and kafka.

Comment: TopologyTestDriver can't be used in above code correct as I am using functional approach. There is not topology and streambuilder used. I have appended my Kstream bean as well in question. @OneCricketeer

Comment: You have a function that accepts a KStream and returns a KStream. Yes, that can be used with `TopologyTestDriver`... More specifically, you would extract out a function you want to test, then simply `return functionToTest(input)` in your Spring code... In other words, remove your business logic from any framework specifics so that you can test it easier

Comment: can you please provide any reference for this @OneCricketeer

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-word-count/src/test/java/kafka/streams/word/count/KafkaStreamsWordCountApplicationTests.java <-- I checked this example as well but it is also not working. I am unable to get message in outputTopic

Answer (score 0):

I recommend removing Spring from the test classpath, if you only care about testing Kafka components such as [this documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/test-streams.html) shows. More importantly, this doesn't require starting an Kafka broker in memory, so it's actually a unit test, not integration test.

Then Spring's KStream function simply defines a sub-Topology which should be extracted into a separate function.

```
public Topology buildTopology() {
  StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
  KStream<String, String> input = builder.stream("input");
  KStream output = functionToTest(input);  // refactored to call from Spring function
  return builder.build();
}

// ... elsewhere
Function<KStream, KStream> process() -> 
    return input -> functionToTest(input);
}
```

Regarding your existing tests, using Consumer and KafkaTemplate aren't testing Kafka Streams actions.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following reference. It is using dependencies with the old version but that's okay. I changed those versions to the newest. And Modified the test producer code as the current one was not working for me. Modifies code as below. This will be useful if you are working with Kafka Avro.

add these annotations for test class

```
@FunctionalSpringBootTest(classes = {<MainClass>Application.class},properties = {"spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092"})
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
        brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092","port=9092","socket.request.max.bytes=409296129"},
        topics = {"so0544in","so0544out"}, controlledShutdown = true)
```

Test producer configuration

```
private Producer<String, Pojoclass> configureProducer() {
        var producerProps = new HashMap<>(KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka));
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, "true");
        producerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "600000");
        producerProps.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "mock://127.0.0.1:8081");
        producerProps.put(BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE, "USER_INFO");
        producerProps.put(USER_INFO_CONFIG, "test:test");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Pojoclass>(producerProps).createProducer();
    }
```

using producer as below in the test case

```
 var producer = configureProducer();
        Pojoclass pojoclass = TestUtility.getSample();
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(INPUT_TOPIC, "key-1", pojoclass));
```